# Bootstrap 5 - column to have auto width while keeping to row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 5 - I have various pages, sometimes 2 columns, sometimes 3.

The template system I'm using tests for the need for the third column and adds it.

```
<div class="container pt-5">
<div class="row gx-5">
<div class="col-sm-12 order-2 order-md-1 col-md-3">
<!-- Left column content here -->     
</div>
<div class="col-sm order-1 col-md-6">
<!-- Center column content here -->     
</div>
<!-- an if statement goes here which I won't bother everyone with-->
<div class="col-sm-12 order-3 col-md-3">
<!-- Right column content here -->     
</div>
<!-- the if statement ends here-->
</div>
</div>
```

This works just fine for a three column layout. But in the template that third column (right column) is sometimes (intentionally dropped). For this two column layout, this layout still works just fine except that the center column NOW needs to be col-md-9 instead of col-md-6.

I can make the template change this, so it's "operational", but I would like to stick with layout being fully handled by bootstrap, so to speak.

I thought well fine, col-md-auto and it should resize to whatever it needs.

If I put in "col-md-auto" in the place of "col-md-6" that center column skips to a new line.

I assume there is either a way to force to row so md-auto spans 9 like I would like it to in that case OR I'm totally missing something.

As always I much appreciate everyone's help.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

With a few comments I received I realize I see I was unclear, with the above bootstrap classes, we get the small breakpoint giving the three columns stacked, with "center" on top, "right column" in the middle, and "left column" last.
Then for anything above "sm", it gives "left column" left, "center column" center, "right column" right

The only problem being when their is no left column (which is a valid condition for this site) the center, in sizes above "sm" needs to take up the remaining space (which would be col-9 when their is no right column, or col-6 when their is).

Comment: `Why not just use a table element?`

Comment: When you say table element, you mean a table dom element or the bootstrap equivalent? My answer would be, though maybe incorrect, is that it's the wrong tool and doesn't necessarily address the situation at hand, but if it does, I would much appreciate any details you could provide. Thank you.

Comment: `@Rogelio how about: <table height="100%"><tr height="100%"><td height="100%">left</td><td height="100%">middle</td><td height="100%">right</td></tr></table>`

Comment: Hello, at a glance the concerns would be a) what you write is not bootstrap and b) it wouldn't handle any of the above described problem unfortunately.

Comment: `Oh. sorry about that.`

Answer (score 2):

Just change `<div class="col-sm order-1 col-md-6">` to `<div class="col order-1">`. Now this column will have auto width.

Whole code

```html
<div class="container pt-5">
  <div class="row gx-5 bg-primary">
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-2 order-md-1 col-md-3 bg-warning">
      <!-- Left column content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col order-1 bg-info">
      <!-- Center column content here -->
    </div>
    <!-- an if statement goes here which I won't bother everyone with-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-3 col-md-3 bg-body">
      <!-- Right column content here -->
    </div>
    <!-- the if statement ends here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad, very much. Please see above, I made some additional notes. I hope that clarifies, it could be my ignorance (and my testing seems to prove out what I am saying here) the above doesn't resolve the problem.  Please let me know and again, thank you for your communication so far.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I was unable to resolve just using bootstrap.
I did need to put an if statement in the templating engine.
So my final code was, the templating engine creating different templates based on two or three column.
I believe my theory was flawed, that it would be better to put this towards bootstrap (in terms of dealing with 2 or 3 columns) when it was really a decision to be made by the templating engine to then generate a 2 column layout with x bootstrap code or three column.
Thank you for eveyones time.
I thought this would be the best way to close it.